# Access Report Running Queries Before Executing Report Open Event

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a query called AdmQuery, a form called Admform and  report called AdmReport. In the Open_Event for Admreport I have called the AdmForm to input start date and end date to two unbound boxes and use that to execute the query and show its results on the report.

This works however the problem is that when I run the report, the query on the report and the open event runs together because of which the form itself opens along with the report (with initially no data on it). Thus i have to close the report , input the dates on the form and then preview the report through another button on the form and everything is fine.

Is there any way to delay the access report running the underlying query only after executing the Report_Open_Event ?

I use access 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `AdmForm` in dialog mode to force `AdmReport`'s `Report_Open` procedure to wait while the user enters date values in `Admform`.

My `AdmForm` includes a command button named `cmdOK`, and it's click event reopens the form in hidden mode, which allows `AdmReport`'s `Report_Open` procedure to continue.  Although `AdmForm` is now hidden, its text boxes and the values they contain will be available to `AdmQuery` (the record source for `AdmReport`).

Here is the code for the command button's click event.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm Me.Name, acNormal, , , , acHidden
End Sub
```

Here is the code behind my version of `AdmReport`.  I tested it with Access 2007, but believe it should work with Access 2003, too.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const mcstrForm As String = "AdmForm"

Private Sub Report_Close()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, mcstrForm
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenForm mcstrForm, acNormal, , , , acDialog
End Sub
```

Notice I included a `Report_Close()` procedure for `AdmReport`.  The purpose is simply to close the (now hidden) `AdmForm`.

Comment: It can often be useful to leave the form open and hidden, I find, because the same dates may be used for a variety of reports or to print the same report again. Of course it depends a lot on the application.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Let me try this and I will get back to you !!

Comment: Excellent.  I read your previous comment that it didn't work with Access 2003, so went to test with 2003.  Now that I'm back I see that you also discovered it does work with Access 2003.

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked something but once i corrected it - it worked like a charm..... thanks again !!